# Where can I see or create this file ~/.tcms.conf

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am trying to follow this instructon: https://github.com/kiwitcms/junit-plugin/ but I don't know where to set this particular file '~/.tcms.conf:'

Configuration and environment
Minimal config file ~/.tcms.conf:

```
   [tcms]
   url = https://tcms.server/xml-rpc/
   username = your-username
   password = your-password
```

I don't know where to look for it or create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/` means your home directory, which in this case is whatever `System.getProperty("user.home")` returns. On Linux this is usually `/home/your-username`.

`.tcms.conf` is the file name inside this directory.